# Selenium Webdriver 4 with Python - Stale Element Reference Exception (stale element reference: stale element not found)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I am working on a Game Playing Bot for Cookie Clicker game. The bot clicks the cookie and buys the items automatically. You would understand what the bot does once you try the game yourself. Link:
https://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/

Problem: Keep getting this exception within seconds of its execution:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
(Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.198)
```

Now I tried executing this multiple times and it crashed at different intervals of time. I even recoded the entire project after multiple executions. From what I understood online, this happens when there's an update in the browser or any user interation during the execution. But I did not touch my keyboard during the execution.
Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url="http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/")
clicker = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cookie"]')
while True:
    clicker.click()
    money = int(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="money"]').text)
    cursor_price = int(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="buyCursor"]/b').text.split()[-1])
    if money > cursor_price:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="buyCursor"]/b').click()
```

Should I try using a different browser?

Comment: it's clearly visible that you're having user interaction when you use `click()` which changes /updates the browser

Answer (score 2):

StaleElement Exception occurs when an element is stale from the DOM sheet, and it probably happens when the page gets refreshed, below code helped me when I am in the same situation.

```
Webelement ele=driver.findelement(By.xpath(""));
wait.until(ExpectedCondition.Invisiblityofelemntlocated(ele));
```

Comment: This is the only approach that resolved my problem, use `Invisiblityofelemntlocated`

Answer (score 0):

### StaleElementReferenceException

[***StaleElementReferenceException***](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException) is thrown when a reference to an element is no longer appears on the DOM of the page and is ***stale***.

Some of the possible causes of StaleElementReferenceException can be:

- You are no longer on the same page, or the page may have refreshed since the element was located.
- The element may have been removed and then re-added again to the screen, since it was initially located.
- Element may have been inside an iframe or another context which was refreshed.

---

### This usecase

In the [Cookie Clicker](https://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/) game to continious click on the cookie till the count is ***15*** and then to click on the **Cursor - 15** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/")
while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='cookie']"))).click()
    money = int(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='money']"))).text)
    cursor_price = int(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='buyCursor']/b"))).text.split()[-1])
    if money > cursor_price:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='buyCursor']/b"))).click()
        break
```

Browser snapshot:

[image: Cookie Clicker]

Comment: i tried adding waits in the code just like you said. it ran longer than previous attempts but still raised the same exception. thanks though appreciate your response!

Comment: never mind i forcibly ran it by neglecting the exception. try and except is a gem!